# Querystring Demo

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application I have productId, ProductName and its Image and I save all the data in database now in someplace of my application  user clicks on Demo Download one inquiry form should be open  And user fill his inquiry and  link of demo will be send to his email. Now that inquiry form should be dynamic, means only one inquiry form for multiple products. So what parameters and how this parameters I should pass with querystring  so that suppose user click on demo for Xyz product then one page should open and its URL is like...
www.abc.com/Inquiry.aspx?Id=1&ProductName=xyz

Comment: So we want to do all the codes???

Comment: No just some of hints

Comment: Id in query string is what productid or userid or customerid

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass productid and productname in querystring like

```
www.abc.com/Inquiry.aspx?Productid=10&Productname=xyz
```

and in Inquiry.aspx page get that query string value first and use anywhere in the page.For getting your querystring value in Inquiry.aspx will be like

```
int product_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Productid"]);
string  productName = Request.QueryString["Productname"];
```

You have to use this type of scenarion.It will be very good if you will pass encrypted value in query string and decrypt it on Inquiry.aspx page.For Encryption and decryption check this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19538/Encrypt-Decrypt-String-using-DES-in-C)

**Second Phase**
declare a string variable as starting like

```
String Productname = "";
String queryProductname =  "";
```

and on page load assign value to Productname like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Productname = "abc";    
queryProductname =  Productname ;     
}
```

and into your anchor tag assign that queryProductname like

```
<a href=\"abc.co.in/test.aspx?period="; + DateTime.Now + " &ProductName=<%= queryProductname %>"\">
```

and for retrieving it's value again use query string like

```
string  productName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
```

This is the scenarion.Hope you understand.

Comment: Here  why u  use  userId  ?????i have only require productId and ProductName .........

Comment: i was thinking id is userid but it's not a issue use productname instead of userid,Actually i am just giving you a hint that how you may complete your work that's why it's doesn't matter that we take userid or productid,,,but check my answer again...i have edit it...

Comment: my that stage is completed.....only productname i have pass and on inquiry form i have retrive that querystring value  succesfully  now the next stage is on submit button of that inquiry form i want to pass another URl  from  downloading the demo of that perticular product only  i have made querystring like  mail.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.abc.co.in/test.aspx?period=" + DateTime.Now + " &ProductName=[]\">Download Demo Software</a>";  now how can i pass this product name ???? and how to retrive it on test.aspx page?

Comment: you need to assign value of your productname from code behind and for retrieve simple get the query string value as we did in inquiry.aspx page...see my edited answer again.i am gonna edit it again for your new work..give me 5 minute.